# How to replace text in a existing file using script on linux?

Tags: perl, shell

I want to replace `abc` with `XYZ`, for which have written below script in a file named `test.sh`; the file is executed on terminal with `sh test.sh` command

```
i='abc';
```

Command:

```
perl -pi -e 's/$i/XZY/g' /home/user/Desktop/file.txt
```

gedit file.txt

But the output is:

```
XYZaXYZbXYZc
XYZ
```

Can't able to figure out the problem.

Comment: Does `$i` contain text (`a*c` should match `a*c`) or a regex (`a*c` should match `acccc`)?

Comment: Can `$i` contain `/`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using single quotes which prevent variable expansion.  So the command you executed is essentially equivalent to saying:

```
perl -pi -e 's//XZY/g' /home/user/Desktop/file.txt
```

which performs the substitution for every character including newlines.

Use double quotes:

```
perl -pi -e "s/$i/XZY/g" /home/user/Desktop/file.txt
```

Comment: Note: fails for `a/b`

Comment: @ikegami Yup, one would use different separator in that case.  But the variable shouldn't contain the separator.

Comment: Then it will fail for that delimiter. That doesn't help at all.

Comment: @ikegami Yes, that is what I mentioned (the variable shouldn't contain the delimiter).

Comment: *Can't*. Or `$`, `@` or `\ `. Or any metacharacters if `$i` is supposed to be matched literally.

Comment: @ikegami I need to read up your posts in spare time, have thought of that several times.  It's been a while since I read some of your posts on perlmonks.  Sincerely, no kidding.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

```
's/$i/XZY/g'
```

The use of single quotes here keeps variable interpolation from happening, so `$i` is passed as a literal to the Perl interpreter.  Since you haven't defined `$i` in your Perl one-liner, the regular expression becomes

```
s//XYZ/g
```

or in other words, insert 'XYZ' after each character in the file.

The solution is to use double-quotes instead.

Answer (score 1):

Characters in single quotes are passed to the program without processing. You're passing the two characters `$i` to Perl, not the value of the shell variable `$i`, so Perl uses the value of its (empty) variable `$i`.

---

If `$i` contains text (`a*c` should match `a*c`), this is the most flexible in what `$i` is allowed to contain:

```
perl -i -pe'BEGIN { $text=shift(@ARGV) } s/\Q$text/XZY/g' "$i" file
```

or

```
TEXT="$i" perl -i -pe's/\Q$ENV{TEXT}/XZY/g' file
```

---

If `$i` contains a regex pattern (`a*c` should match `a*cccc`), then you want:

```
perl -i -pe'BEGIN { $re=shift(@ARGV) } s/$re/XZY/g' "$i" file
```

or

```
RE="$i" perl -i -pe's/$ENV{RE}/XZY/g' file
```

Comment: Forgot to actually pass `$i` to the script! Fixed, and added shorter alternate solution.

Comment: I guess the last example (the one with `ENV`) wouldn't work unless the environment variable is `export`ed.  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use double quotes(`"`) instead of single quotes(`'`).  Single quotes are used for literal strings.

```
perl -pi -e "s/$i/XZY/g" /home/user/Desktop/file.txt
```

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=401006

To match a `/` you have to escape it. `\/`.  The new problem is that you have to escape the `\` when you are building you original string.

```
i="a\\/b";
perl -pi -e "s/$i/XZY/g" /home/user/Desktop/file.txt
```

Comment: Note: fails for `a/b`